# Receiving 0 results from my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a stored procedure in SQL Server and I'm getting 0 results. I initially had this running just fine (attached to SSRS) but then users requested a multiple value input for the ProviderName parameter and I realized I was in over my head. I contacted our vendor who provided a KnowledgeBase article which I essentially copied and pasted right in. See below...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
   (@dStartDate DATETIME
   ,@dEndDate DATETIME
   ,@nProviderName VARCHAR(MAX)
   ,@nAllProviderName VARCHAR(1) = 'N')
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dStart AS DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,@dStartDate)) ;
    DECLARE @dEnd   AS DATETIME = DATEADD(ms,-3, DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,@dEndDate))))
    DECLARE @cProviderName AS VARCHAR(MAX) = @nProviderName
    DECLARE @tProviderName AS TABLE (PCPID VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

    IF UPPER(@nAllProviderName) = 'N'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tPCPName ( PCPID )
           SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) 
           FROM [dbo].[Auto_Split]('|',@nProviderName ) ;
    END;

    SELECT      ...

    WHERE   
       ([TestMnemonic] = 'GLU' OR
        [TestMnemonic] = '%HA1C')       
       AND [Status] != 'DIS CLI'        
       AND [TextLine] IS NOT NULL           
       AND [DateTime] BETWEEN @dStart AND @dEnd 
       AND (UPPER(@nAllProviderName) = 'Y' OR
            [PCPID] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
               IN (SELECT PCPID FROM @tProviderName ) ) ; 
END
```

So if I comment out the last 4 lines of code it runs fine. So it's something in that last bit (or something at the top?) I'm hoping this is a quick fix, any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch @tProviderName with @tPCPName in last line.

If your @nAllProviderName is "N" than you search PCPID from memory table called @tPCPName

And there is some code missing, so I didn't get the full picture .. If you could put your from and joins statments and your missing "where clause", when your @nAllProviderName is "Y"

and you don't need this part in your SQL

```
IF UPPER(@nAllProviderName) = 'N'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tPCPName ( PCPID )
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) 
       FROM [dbo].[Auto_Split]('|',@nProviderName ) ;
END
```

if you switch your last line with

```
 AND (UPPER(@nAllProviderName) = 'Y' OR
            [PCPID] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
               IN ( SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) 
           FROM [dbo].[Auto_Split]('|',@nProviderName ) ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the Collate statement at the bottom.  What us your system default and do you really need that when comparing against a temp table you made?

Without Collate

```
OR [PCPID] IN (SELECT PCPID FROM @tProviderN
```